# Git Plugin showing git data revision for Jenkinsfile related repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have just upgraded our jenkins to 2.289.1 version. With the latest upgradation,the git plugin has started showing git data for the repositories of our Jenkinsfile as well. This did not happen with the earlier versions of jenkins.

Is there any way around where the git data for the service is being shown or downgrade is the only option that we have??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no obvious issue report (as seen in [this search query](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63581?jql=(component%20%3D%2015543%20and%20summary%7E%22revision%22)%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)) which matches your issue, for the [Git Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/), the next steps would be:

- to confirm this is linked to Jenkins (downgrade)
- or linked to the plugin (keep 2.289.1 and downgrade the plugin)
- or linked to another plugin

And then report the bug for the appropriate Jenkins component (Jenkins core, or one of its plugins).